# Anaconda Python 3.6 -- pythonw and python supposed to be equivalent?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.6

According to Python 3 documentation, python and pythonw should be equivalent for running GUI scripts [as of 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html#running-scripts-with-a-gui)

> With older versions of Python, there is one Mac OS X quirk that you need to be aware of: programs that talk to the Aqua window manager (in other words, anything that has a GUI) need to be run in a special way. Use pythonw instead of python to start such scripts.
>
> With Python 3.6, you can use either python or pythonw.

However, I just installed Anaconda with Python 3.6, and I still get the non-framework-build error if I try to run my wxPython GUI using python instead of pythonw:

```
This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a
Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in
on the main display of your Mac.
```

What is going on here?  Why does this error persist?

The version of Python I am using is:

```
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)
```

Comment: `python --version` says?

Comment: I have this same issue. My `python --version` says `Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)`

Answer (score 4):

The answer can be found here: [How to use a framework build of Python with Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707656/how-to-use-a-framework-build-of-python-with-anaconda)

In short, use command

```
conda install python.app
```

and pythonw will be installed.

Comment: My issue is not that pythonw is missing.  It is that this: `With Python 3.6, you can use either python or pythonw.`  appears not to be true.  It would be helpful for me, for cross-platform reasons, not to have to mess with pythonw at all.

Comment: I have the same issue. How do we tell `conda` to use `pythonw` after having installed `python.app` ?

Comment: I wish, as does J. Jones, that pythonw was not needed. But Anaconda has their reasons, no doubt. I am not sure what you mean by wanting conda to use pythonw. If you want to run a script with the framework version of Python, you can start it by in a terminal window by typing "pythonw script.py" rather than "python script.py". You can tell other applications such as spyder to use pythonw rather than python. Perhaps a starting a new question linked here would make what you want to do more clear.

Comment: The problem seems to be that OS X will not allow access to the screen unless the program is running from inside an application bundle. There is nothing special about the pythonw that anaconda supplies (in fact as I write this it has some serious bugs). If I take an existing python interpreter and "wrap" it inside an "Application.app" bundle, where the bundle executable is a soft link to the python interpreter, I can then use that to run wx applications

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can also just run your python script using `pythonw` instead of `python`. You'll need to use `pythonw` for GUI related programs.