# How to use a framework build of Python with Anaconda

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I'm unable to get matplotlib animations to display on a Mac computer.  I've chased down several attempts at installing ffmpeg but they've all failed and I'm starting to wonder if that isn't the wrong way to solve the problem.

I found [this](http://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html) page.

Since I'm running Python from the Spyder app in Anaconda, the section for this seems relevant.  It says

> The default python provided in (Ana)Conda is not a framework build.
>   However, the Conda developers have made it easy to install a framework
>   build in both the main environment and in Conda envs. To use this
>   install python.app `conda install python.app` and use `pythonw` rather
>   than `python`

I'm not perfectly clear on what this means, but I opened a terminal, ran `conda install python.app` and it seemed to work--at least there were no error messages.  I could navigate to a folder that contained the file `python.app`.

I'm not clear on what it means to "use `pythonw`" but I navigated to the animation I'm trying to compile and ran `$ pythonw anim.py` and it gave me an I/O error.  I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use `pythonw` in some other way, or what.  If I restart and try to run the code in Spyder I get the same error as before.

I know that the code works, because I've run it on a Linux machine that has ffmpeg and it worked.

Is there something else I need to do to get a framework build, whatever that means?

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. The code seems to work in Python console but now the Interactive one?

Comment: I had a similar problem that was solved by setting the `matplotlib` backend to `TkAgg` instead of the default `MacOS`, i.e. by doing `echo "backend: TkAgg" > ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` [as described here](https://enigma.co/catalyst/install.html#macos).

Answer (score 0):

After installing the framework build, you have to change the location of your python interpreter from python to pythonw. I am not familiar with Spyder, but in VS code I solved this issue modifying the settings.json file from

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/[username]/miniconda3/envs/base-evn/bin/python"
}
```

to

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/[username]/miniconda3/envs/base-evn/bin/pythonw"
}
```

I am using minicoda. For anaconda, the folder in your home directory might be named one of the following:

anaconda2.
anaconda3.