# Mac PyQt5 menubar not active until unfocusing-refocusing the app

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyqt5

I have problems in creating the Qt menubar using PyQt5 in Mac.

The problem I have is the menubar would show up, **but won't react until I unfocus the app (by clicking the other app), then refocus the Qt app again.**

Here's my environment:

OS: Sierra 10.12

Python: Python 3.6 from conda

PyQt5: conda default(v5.3.1)

Here's my code (mostly from http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/menustoolbars/):

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, QDesktopWidget, QApplication, qApp, QMenuBar

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')

        exitAction = QAction(' &Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl-Q')
        exitAction.setToolTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        self.show()

    def center(self):

        center_point = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        frame = self.frameGeometry()
        frame.moveCenter(center_point)
        self.move(frame.topLeft())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The picture below shows the menu bar is present, but it just won't respond to my click until I select other app and return to my Qt app again.

[image]
I've searched many site and found no solution. The closest one is this (https://github.com/robotology/yarp/issues/457) but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Update your version of PyQt, the current version is PyQt 5.10, probably in later versions that problem has been solved. https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5

Comment: Unfortunately, conda only have PyQt 5.6. I do not want to do pip install due to potential risk of breaking things (see https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1970). Seems I'm stuck.

Comment: Version 5.3.1 is very old so I think that for that version has no solution, you should use the LTS versions such as version 5.6 or 5.9

Answer (score 6):

Run your code using **pythonw** rather than **python3**. So for example, if your file is called *test-gui.py*, in the command line terminal, type in:

`pythonw test-gui.py`

This fixed the error for me. It treats the code as an executable, so the OS isn't confused as to what is being run.

Comment: With MacOS 10.15.7 and PyQt5 5.15.4 this doesn't work for me.  If I do the command above, then I get errors    

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

If I change the shebang line to pythonw instead of python3 I get the same behaviour, no active menu button until I defocus/refocus.

Comment: I had the same issue as @PeterCorke. For me the fix was to run `conda install python.app` - as detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47385209/10557583.

This allowed pythonw to run inside the conda env without the no module errors